# What am I doing wrong in the following SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE find employees
  2  BEGIN
  3  if Department_ID < 50 from Employees
  4  THEN
  5  RETURN select Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Department_ID from Employees where Department_ID < 50;
  6  ELSE
  7  RETURN select Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Department_ID from Employees where Department_ID > 50;
  8  END IF;
  9  /
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: What errors? Are the line numbers literally part of this or is that just junk that was pasted in?

Comment: Most of this doesn't look like sql.   if Department_ID < 50 from Employees?  Does this proc take any input?

Comment: 2 things: 1) Look like you're missing a trailing `END` to close the `BEGIN` and 2) please don't tell me sql server allows spaces in procedure names ie that it allows the name to be `"find employees"`

Comment: Dude, everything is wrong here. Your code sample, your stored procedure name, your `if` statement. How you are returning the results. How to are closing your `if`...

Comment: This is NOT t-sql at all. This looks like oracle code.

Comment: @SeanLange - heh, funny since he's tagged as sql-server.   Kinda resembles SAS scripting to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing about this makes sense.

Return can only return integers and is used only for returning error codes.

This is an incorrect use of If as well in two different ways.  Where are you getting the value of Department_id? And look up the syntax for If as you are way off.
Of course you wouldn't have line numbers in the actual stored proc.

It is a poor practice to name a proc with spaces, do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

A number of issues I can see (assuming per the tag that this is MS-SQL):

1. `find employees` isn't a valid proc name, due to the space. To absolutely force it to accept the space (warning: bad idea!!) you could surround it in brackets like `[find employees]` but I would definitely recommend something like `find_employees` instead.
2. You are missing an `END` to signify the end of your proc.
3. You don't use `RETURN` inside a stored proc, only inside a function. Are you trying to pass a result set to whatever called it (in which case you'd need a "table-valued function")? Or just display the results?
4. Are you trying to *pass in* `Department_ID`? In other words, to give it a different `Department_ID` each time you run? In that case you'll need a `@Department_ID` parameter or something. Or is it getting it from a table?
5. I can't fathom your business logic, it makes no sense. Why are you returning two different lists of employees? Are you trying to *count* how many employees belong to each dept? Is this some kind of "paging" logic (retrieving only 50 employees at a time)?
6. Your `IF` syntax is way off. should be something like `IF @Department_ID < 50` (for a parameter) or maybe `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE Department_ID = @Department_ID) > 50` or something, but again, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what you're trying to do.
7. SQL doesn't use `END IF`. Look up the syntax for single-line IF ELSE statements and multi-line IF ELSE statements.

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Yep.

Answer (score 0):

there is no END to the CREATE statement... 
There is no definition of department_id... 
there are no parameters declared for the IF statement to work on...
The function name has a space in it...